# reducer goes into a loop when returning a new array created from state

Tags: react-redux

I am using react-redux 5.0.6 and have a reducer with the following code:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ENGAGEMENT':
      let newArr = state.slice();
      newArr.push(action.payload);
      return newArr;
    case 'UPDATE_ENGAGEMENT':
      console.info('UPDATE_ENGAGEMENT')
      return state.slice();
      // return state;
  default:
    return state;
  }}
```

The issue occurs within the 'UPDATE_ENGAGEMENT' case -- the actual logic has been removed and replaced with the simplest example to demonstrate the problem.

When a new array created from state via state.slice() is returned, a loop is triggered, causing the action to be dispatched until an 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' error is raised. [Screenshot of the browser console during the issue's occurrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQZWh.png)

The issue is not limited to 'slice()' and occurs whenever an array containing any element of state is returned e.g. return [state[0]].
When the original state is returned, the issue does not occur. 
I am completely baffled by this behavior and cannot fathom how anything in my application could be causing it. Any insight would be immensely appreciated.

To provide some additional context, below is the code involved in the action's being dispatched:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  let engagementTemplateData = newProps.selectedEngagementTemplate;
  let engagements = newProps.engagements;

  if (engagementTemplateData && engagementTemplateData.engagementUuid === this.props.uuid) {
    let template = engagementTemplateData.template;
    this.updateEngagementTemplate(template);
   }
 }

 updateEngagementTemplate(template) {
   let url = `/engagements/${this.props.uuid}`;
   let requestHelper = new AjaxRequestHelper(url);
   let data = {template_uuid: template.uuid};
   this.props.updateEngagement({uuid: this.props.uuid, template: template});
   // requestHelper.put(data, response => {
    //   this.props.updateEngagement({uuid: this.props.uuid, template: template});
    // });
  }
```

Basically, the function which triggers the action is called in componentWillReceiveProps as a result of another action. However, I am not sure how helpful this information is, since the reducer itself appears to be working properly when responding to the action -- it's just that something strange is happening with the state, which prevents its elements from being returned.

Comment: So if it happens only if you update the state then somewhere in your react components you have componentWillReceiveProps or componentWillUpdate  which basically call this action whenever you change a state. Could you show the place where you call this action?

Comment: Updated description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it (and from the react callstack), I imagine the array changing (by reference) in the store is being picked up by a react component props, which in its should/did update logic is calling that action without a guard. This is often a mistake when calling actions or `setState` from `componentDidMount/Update` -

It works when the original state is returned as the reference is the same so React does not continue with its update logic, and hence call your code that publishes the action

Consider this pure component that will cause an endless loop with your reducer code...

```
export interface IMyProps {
  myArray: any[],
  updateEngagementAction: () => void
}

export class EndlessLoopFromArrayPropComponent extends React.PureComponent<IMyProps> {

  // PureComponent compares props by reference only 
  // so will cause update if this.props.myArray reference has changed in store (ie from slice())

  render() {
    // blahblah...
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // this will call action after every update
    // as every time this action is called it passes in a new reference this.props.myArray to this component
    // so react will update this component again, causing the action to be called again
    // ... endless loop
    this.props.updateEngagementAction()
  }

}
```

Your implementation will differ of course but this will be the principal that is causing it to happen, so you need to add a guard condition in whatever code path leads to your action being called.

For the code above you would need to check an escape condition before sending the action OR implement `shouldComponentUpdate` or similar to do deeper prop comparison to guard against unnecessary updates, and hence it would not reach that action code in the `componentDidUpdate` method

**EDIT** This was written before the react code was added to question. Here I refer to the action being called without guard in `componentDidUpdate` however the same applies when called in any of the other lifecycle methods triggered by a prop change, in this case `componentWillRecieveProps`. To be fair it did have a guard already, but never returned false as a more in-depth props check was needed, so caused a loop to occur via `willreceive -> true  -> action -> reducer -> willreceive -> true ........`

Comment: Please see the updated description -- the action is triggered in a function which is called from componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: Exactly the same principal `if (engagementTemplateData && engagementTemplateData.engagementUuid === this.props.uuid) {` is never returning false when new props are passed in, hence your action is triggered again. And `componentWillRecieveProps` is always called becuase you are passing in a brand new engagements array by reference

Comment: You're absolutely right. The conditional was returning true, which I found surprising because the reducer was returning an engagements array, but newProps also contained a value for selectedEngagementTemplate, which was set prior to the action in question. I suppose the props passed to componentWillReceiveProps contain the full application state and not just the state updated by the most recent action.

Comment: Internally redux state acts immutably. That is whenever you return anything even from a leaf reducer, the entire store state is copied and then your change is mapped onto the new store state. React-redux sees this new store state change and passes it to mapStateToProps, which ends up passing all the parts of state you mapped to your react component. So yep newProps will always be a complete set of props rather than only the 'changed' subset, not the entire application state, but all the ones you have mapped to props

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help and insight!